# Debug/Fix "Exceeded maximum execution time" error Google Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I've created my first Google Workspace Addon which I have deployed to the associated domain successfully although still working on it due to this error.

Without errors, functionally it's (was) working well, however, I now keep getting "Exceeded maximum execution time" errors.

This error is frustratingly intermittent, but it recently started occuring around 90%+ of the time despite not occurring previously for weeks. Reverting to previous versions of my code hasn't fixed the issue.

Most if not all existing answers regarding this error assume the script is genuinely exceeding the time limit for scripts (either 6 minutes or 30 minutes).

*To be clear - this is not what's happening here.* The script doesn't run for anywhere close to the maximum time allowed (as far as I'm aware). It actually runs for around 45 seconds before giving the error.

It may somehow be running in the background and causing a legitimate Timeout error but I need to figure out if this is the case and the cause of the error and then fix it.

I've contacted Google but their relevant support who are knowledgeable about this and who could help are unfortunately very difficult to get hold of.

In Cloud Logging for this error, I'm seeing (obfuscated id's):

```
{
  "insertId": "28z8v2anf1xq6",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "context": {
      "reportLocation": {
        "filePath": "[unknown file]",
        "functionName": "[unknown function]"
      }
    },
    "message": "Exceeded maximum execution time",
    "serviceContext": {
      "service": "AKfycbx-SO5mXBNoe2leEH4wrj02t9fZZwkq5BQlJPuBaNM"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "app_script_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "fileMakerPro",
      "invocation_type": "unknown",
      "project_id": "order-management-713317"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-03-10T10:09:58.827Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "fIxbX5X5IjrIqLLK-XQgJiJV0U9vQMEAEA1GOxTqw-XzqsaVlKTNK2UcymM7feuXp-qZLshvBUg61TS6u28l_v6szoAq8QBBOvGudISVj0yceQXPKpIHO6HJ2G-uxuqy4xcnv-NzDfBTMbJH7VmK_AjZd6a5KVA-LnhtOE_28mCn_zTpI5AC3-BhX_lcCC1p-3QsMX6blhMZSYgVTTo1T_Z9SovufUWinpJieIbio-L8wzQPkjLYM2l9s5RHGuKMcT3LbvUO7fFS4DV1z_xfaR_nU1LqeayAk1aouGSXc",
    "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "wPo7ZL4DSIqpPrZfeqo7E7yAArA430YCNnzbVYhyuVlR6nKybMkISeaDZoigRDx0gAJXIjF49EoL",
    "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "wkq5BQlJPcbx-SO5mEHAKfywrj02t9fZZ4uBXBNoe2leaNM",
    "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "Xf9t90MIwJJbMnu2Z9hQ48TM6DPTcW9w3"
  },
  "logName": "projects/order-management-317713/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-03-10T10:09:59.313440894Z"
}
```

Which is obscure and isn't helpful at all with the "unknowns".

The function it references, for reference:

```
async function fileMakerPro(e) {
  console.time("fileMakerPro");

  //Order Management Named Ranges
  let OM_NR = await getNamedRangesAsObject_(ss);
  
  let orderNumber, orderFolder, orderFolderName;
  let loadingDate, loadingDateFormatted, dueDate, dueDateFormatted;

  let sheetGoodsTable = OM_NR.goodsTable.ranges.filter(function (x) { /* here, x is an array, not an object */
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  });

  //Get order number if exists or show warning and return
  if (orderNumber = OM_NR.OrderNo.range.toString()) {

  } else {
    ui.alert(`⚠️  ORDER NUMBER \(${OM_NR.OrderNo.rangeA1.toString()}\) appears missing, please correct and try again.`);
    return;
  }
  //Get loading date if exists or show warning and return
  if (loadingDate = OM_NR.transportLoadingDate.range) {

    loadingDateFormatted = `${loadingDate.getDate()}-${loadingDate.getMonth() + 1}-${loadingDate.getFullYear()}`;
    monthName = monthNames[loadingDate.getMonth()];

    //Set Due Date 30 days after Loading Date
    dueDate = new Date(loadingDate.getFullYear(), loadingDate.getMonth(), loadingDate.getDate() + 30);
    dueDateFormatted = `${dueDate.getDate()}-${dueDate.getMonth() + 1}-${dueDate.getFullYear()}`;


  } else {
    ui.alert(`⚠️ LOADING DATE \(${OM_NR.transportLoadingDate.rangeA1.toString()}\) appears to be missing, please correct and try again.`);
    return;
  }

  let rootFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).getParents().next();
  let tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1f4Ll-KODzmvBIuunaCS_7anMCX-w86S6");
  let monthFolders = rootFolder.getFolders();
  let tickBoxes = e.formInputs.generateDocsCheckboxes;


  let packingListTemplateId = '1cZUB4U59Z56456gdgdghhka2QQ9sUNIlQSHYy1M';
  let tickCMR = false, tickInvoice = false;

  //Find existing order folder
  let orderSearch = await searchFolders(monthFolders, monthName, orderNumber);

  //Set Order Folder Name if both values present
  orderFolderName = `${loadingDate.getDate()}-${loadingDate.getMonth() + 1}-${loadingDate.getFullYear()} \(${orderNumber}\)`;


  if (tickBoxes !== undefined) {
    if (tickBoxes.indexOf('tickBoxCMRnote') > -1) {
      tickCMR = true;
    }
    if (tickBoxes.indexOf('tickBoxInvoice') > -1) {
      tickInvoice = true;
    }
  } else {
    let confirm = ui.alert(`⚠️ No documents selected. Update Order ${orderNumber} Snapshot and Packing List only?`, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (confirm === ui.Button.YES) {
      fileMakerPro();
    } else {
      ss.toast(`⚠️ Update cancelled.`);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (!orderSearch.foundMonthFolder) {
    ss.toast(`⚙️ Creating Month Folder...`);
    monthFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(monthName);
  } else {
    monthFolder = orderSearch.foundMonthFolder;
  }

  if (!orderSearch.foundOrderFolder) {
    ss.toast(`⚙️ Creating Order Folder...`);
    orderFolder = monthFolder.createFolder(orderFolderName);
  } else {
    if (!orderSearch.foundOrderFolder.getName().includes(loadingDateFormatted)) {
      ui.alert(`⚠️ Duplicate Order Number ${orderNumber} found: ${orderSearch.foundMonthFolder.getName()} / ${orderSearch.foundOrderFolder.getName()}.\n\n Please change Order Number or remove duplicate Order Folder.`);
      return;
    }
    orderFolder = orderSearch.foundOrderFolder;
  }


  if (tickInvoice && tickCMR) {
  
      assembleCMR(orderFolder, orderNumber, tempFolder, loadingDateFormatted, sheetGoodsTable, OM_NR);
      assembleInvoice(orderFolder, orderNumber, tempFolder, loadingDateFormatted, dueDateFormatted, sheetGoodsTable, OM_NR);

      ss.toast(`✅ Documents Saved`);


  } else {
    if (tickCMR) {

        assembleCMR(orderFolder, orderNumber, tempFolder, loadingDateFormatted, sheetGoodsTable, OM_NR);

        ss.toast(`✅ CMR Document Saved`);

    }
    if (tickInvoice) {

        assembleInvoice(orderFolder, orderNumber, tempFolder, loadingDateFormatted, dueDateFormatted, sheetGoodsTable, OM_NR);

        ss.toast(`✅ Invoice Document Saved`);

    }
  }

  let existingOrderSnapshot = orderFolder.getFilesByName(`${orderNumber} - ORDER SNAPSHOT - DO NOT EDIT`);
  let existingPackingList = orderFolder.getFilesByName(`${orderNumber} - PACKING LIST`);

  let packingListId = await createPackingList(existingPackingList, orderFolder, orderNumber, packingListTemplateId, sheetId, OM_NR);

  
  createOrderSnapshot(existingOrderSnapshot, orderFolder, orderNumber, sheetId, packingListId);

  syncOrderNumbers(orderSearch.orderNumbers);


  console.timeEnd("fileMakerPro");

  return;
}
```

I suspect *maybe* the following function could be causing the Timeout since the loop may be malfunctioning but not sure how to check or fix:

```
async function writePackingList(OM_NR, packingList, packingListId){
    let PL_NR = await getNamedRangesAsObject_(packingList);

    for (let nr in PL_NR) {
      Logger.log(nr);

      if (nr == "loadingAddress") {
        packingList.getRangeByName(`${nr}`).setValue(OM_NR[`${nr}`].range);
      } else if (nr) {
        packingList.getRangeByName(`${nr}`).setValue(OM_NR[`${nr}`].range);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    ss.getRangeByName("transportTotalNetWeight").setFormula(`=IMPORTRANGE("${packingListId}", "PL!I15")`)
    ss.getRangeByName("transportTotalGrossWeight").setFormula(`=IMPORTRANGE("${packingListId}", "PL!H15")`)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've hit a brick wall with this. I need to figure out how to debug this error, understand why it's happening and fix it so it doesn't happen when fully deployed.

Thanks

EDIT to include additional functions:

```
//Make copy of Invoice template doc, get body, replace all placeholders, return 
async function assembleInvoice(orderFolder, orderNumber, tempFolder, loadingDateFormatted, dueDateFormatted, sheetGoodsTable, OM_NR) {
  console.time("assembleInvoice");

  ss.toast(`⚙️ Assembling Invoice Document...`);
  let prefix = orderNumber + " - ";
  let fileName = "INVOICE";
  let templateTempCopy;

  //Blue Invoice Template
  let invoiceTemplate1 = DriveApp.getFileById("C2j_q3nUP4UTUR1KiCt07r1lATPKSjzEm-EeY109T8B4");
  //Red Invoice Template
  let invoiceTemplate2 = DriveApp.getFileById("1uczJT-F-JzKzaBwh_CdhJNcFkgDHfGjypJYom4vqGIo");

  //Choose Invoice template based on Movement Type
  let staraMovementType = OM_NR.staraMovementType.range;


  if (staraMovementType.toString().includes('GB SHIPPING TO')) {
    templateTempCopy = invoiceTemplate1.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  } else {
    templateTempCopy = invoiceTemplate1.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  }


  //Open working copy
  let workingCopy = DocumentApp.openById(templateTempCopy.getId());

  //Get body from working copy
  let documentBody = workingCopy.getBody();


  //Populate table
  let allTables = documentBody.getTables();
  let invoiceGoodsTable = allTables[3];

  let itemRowTemplate = invoiceGoodsTable.getRow(invoiceGoodsTable.getNumRows() - 2);
  let totalsRowTemplate = invoiceGoodsTable.getRow(invoiceGoodsTable.getNumRows() - 1);


  for (let n in sheetGoodsTable) {
    let tableRow = invoiceGoodsTable.appendTableRow(itemRowTemplate.copy());

    tableRow.getCell(0).replaceText("{itemNo}", sheetGoodsTable[n][1]);
    tableRow.getCell(1).replaceText("{itemDesc}", sheetGoodsTable[n][0]);
    tableRow.getCell(2).replaceText("{commodityCode}", sheetGoodsTable[n][2]);
    tableRow.getCell(3).replaceText("{cartons}", sheetGoodsTable[n][4]);
    tableRow.getCell(4).replaceText("{qtyKgs}", sheetGoodsTable[n][5]);
    tableRow.getCell(5).replaceText("{price}", sheetGoodsTable[n][3]);
    tableRow.getCell(6).replaceText("{total}", sheetGoodsTable[n][5] * sheetGoodsTable[n][3]);
  }

  let totalsRow = invoiceGoodsTable.appendTableRow(totalsRowTemplate.copy());

  totalsRow.getCell(3).replaceText("{cartons}", OM_NR.transportCasesCartons.range);
  totalsRow.getCell(4).replaceText("{qtyKgs}", OM_NR.transportTotalNetWeight.range);
  totalsRow.getCell(6).replaceText("{total}", OM_NR.transportInvoiceTotal.range);


  itemRowTemplate.removeFromParent();
  totalsRowTemplate.removeFromParent();

  let importerAddress = `${OM_NR.importerConsigneeIntoEU.range}, ${OM_NR.importerAddress.range}`;

  documentBody.replaceText("{currency}", OM_NR.staraInvoiceCurrency.range);

  documentBody.replaceText("{shipToAddress}", importerAddress);

  documentBody.replaceText("{billToAddress}", importerAddress);

  documentBody.replaceText("{exporterCustomsInvoiceNo}", OM_NR.exporterCustomsInvoiceNo.range);

  documentBody.replaceText("{exporterVAT}", OM_NR.exporterVAT.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{exporterEORI}", OM_NR.exporterEORI.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{staraOrderNo}", OM_NR.staraOrderNo.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{staraCustomerOrderNo}", OM_NR.staraCustomerOrderNo.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{transportLoadingDate}", loadingDateFormatted);

  documentBody.replaceText("{dueDate}", dueDateFormatted);

  documentBody.replaceText("{paymentTerms}", "30 DAYS");
  documentBody.replaceText("{staraInvoiceNo}", OM_NR.staraInvoiceNo.range);

  documentBody.replaceText("{incoTerms}", `${OM_NR.orderIncoterm.range} ${OM_NR.orderCountryOfDestination.range}`);
  documentBody.replaceText("{transportTotalGrossWeight}", OM_NR.transportTotalGrossWeight.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{transportTotalNetWeight}", OM_NR.transportTotalNetWeight.range);

  documentBody.replaceText("{transportTruckRef}", OM_NR.transportTruckRef.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{transportSeal1}", OM_NR.transportSeal1.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{transportSeal2}", OM_NR.transportSeal2.range);

  documentBody.replaceText("{transportInvoiceTotal}", OM_NR.transportInvoiceTotal.range);
  documentBody.replaceText("{staraInvoiceCurrency}", OM_NR.staraInvoiceCurrency.range);


  workingCopy.saveAndClose();


  //Gets a 'blob' of the completed document
  let completedDoc = templateTempCopy.getAs('application/pdf');

  //Check for existing PDF and move to trash (not fully delete)
  let foundFile = orderFolder.getFilesByName(prefix + fileName);
  if (foundFile.hasNext()) {
    foundFile.next().setTrashed(true);
  }

  try {
    //Create PDF
    ss.toast(` Saving ${fileName} PDF...`);

    orderFolder.createFile(completedDoc).setName(prefix + fileName);

    deleteTempFiles(templateTempCopy.getId());

  } catch (err) {
    showError(err);
  } finally {
    ss.toast(`✅ Invoice Document Saved`);
    console.timeEnd("assembleInvoice");

  }
  return;
}
```

```
async function createPackingList(existingPackingList, orderFolder, orderNumber, packingListTemplateId, sheetId, OM_NR) {
  console.time("createPackingList");

    let packingListId;
    //Get current sheet container objects and data
    if (existingPackingList.hasNext()) {
      packingListId = existingPackingList.next().getId();
    } else {
      ss.toast(` Creating Packing List...`);
      let newPackingList = DriveApp.getFileById(packingListTemplateId);
      let newPackingListCopy = newPackingList.makeCopy(`${orderNumber} - PACKING LIST`, orderFolder)
      packingListId = newPackingListCopy.getId();
    }

    let packingList = SpreadsheetApp.openById(packingListId);
    addImportrangePermission(packingListId, sheetId);

    writePackingList(OM_NR, packingList, packingListId);


    ss.toast(`✅ Packing List Created/Updated`);
    console.timeEnd("createPackingList");
    return packingListId;
}
```

```
async function createOrderSnapshot(existingOrderSnapshot, orderFolder, orderNumber, sheetId, packingListId) {
  console.time("createOrderSnapshot");

  let snapshotExists = existingOrderSnapshot.hasNext();

    //If snapshot exists, delete.
    if (snapshotExists) {
      existingOrderSnapshot.next().setTrashed(true);
      ss.toast(` Updating Order Snapshot...`);
    } else {
      ss.toast(` Creating Order Snapshot...`);
    }

    //Make copy of sheet in order folder
    let currentSheet =  DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId);
    let sheetCopy = currentSheet.makeCopy(`${orderNumber} - ORDER SNAPSHOT - DO NOT EDIT`, orderFolder);
    let sheetCopyId = sheetCopy.getId();
    let targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetCopyId);
    

    //let targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).makeCopy(`${orderNumber} - ORDER SNAPSHOT - DO NOT EDIT`, orderFolder).getId());

    addImportrangePermission(targetSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("CONTROL").getValue(), sheetCopyId);
    addImportrangePermission(packingListId, sheetCopyId);

    targetSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("transportTotalNetWeight").setFormula(`=IMPORTRANGE("${packingListId}", "PL!I15")`)
    targetSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("transportTotalGrossWeight").setFormula(`=IMPORTRANGE("${packingListId}", "PL!H15")`)

    targetSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("topRow").clearDataValidations()
    targetSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("sheetBody").clearDataValidations()

    //DELETE UNNEEDED TABS FROM COPY
    targetSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("PC"));
    targetSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("C1"));
    targetSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("C2"));
    targetSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("SFC"));


    if (snapshotExists) {
      ss.toast(`✅ Order Snapshot Updated`);
    } else {
      ss.toast(`✅ Order Snapshot Created`);
    }
    console.timeEnd("createOrderSnapshot");
  
  return;
}
```

```
async function addImportrangePermission(sourceSheetId, authSheetId) {
  console.time("addImportrangePermission");
  if (sourceSheetId) {
    // donor or source spreadsheet id

    // adding permission by fetching this url
    let url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${authSheetId}/externaldata/addimportrangepermissions?donorDocId=${sourceSheetId}`;

    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    let params = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  }
  console.timeEnd("addImportrangePermission");
  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide information about the context in which `fileMakerPro` is running? How it is triggered? If this is coming from a single trigger or a custom function, the limit would be 30 seconds, not 6 minutes. Also, about `It actually runs for around 45 seconds before giving the error.`, are you seeing this in the logs, or how do you know that? Finally, can you use `console.time` on the different parts of the function to check where it is taking most time?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for reply. `fileMakerPro` is triggered using `.setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('fileMakerPro'))`. 45 seconds is a manual timing after clicking the button to end of run. I've recently made use of `console.time` and got: `searchFolders: 416ms`, `assembleCMR: 9939ms`, `assembleInvoice: 9580ms`, `addImportrangePermission: 873ms`, `createPackingList: 10872ms`, `addImportrangePermission: 1530ms`, `addImportrangePermission: 808ms` for a (now) rare complete run. These are all the functions called by `fileMakerPro`, in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

In Workspace add-ons, callback functions executed when an [Action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action) triggers are limited to **30 seconds of execution time**:

> The Apps Script [Card service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) limits callback functions to a maximum of 30 seconds of execution time. If the execution takes longer than that, your add-on UI may not update its card display properly in response to the [Action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action).

#### Note:

Since you didn't provide the code related to the functions which are taking most time (e.g. `assembleCMR`, `assembleInvoice`, `createPackingList`) I cannot make any suggestion on that, but in any case you should try to improve the efficiency of those functions, or split it all into several `Actions`.

#### Reference:

- [Callback functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/actions#callback_functions)

Comment: Ah, it's starting to make sense now. Didn't realise the 30 sec limit on Action triggers. Strange it seems to last for for 45 though. I've updated my question with the additional functions code so you can see what they do. I was aiming for the functions referenced in `fileMakerPro` to all run with a single button click, without the Timeout errors. To get there, looks like I'll need to reorganise my code or else speed it up significantly. If there are any obvious improvements/optimisations I can make I'd appreciate any feedback or suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Diagonali Some suggestions would be: try to set multiple values at once for a multi-cell range, and not set each value separately in `writePackingList` (since you are using named ranges, I'm not sure how feasible is that). Create the tables directly in `assembleInvoice`, instead of replacing each placeholder every time. In any case, I'd suggest you to file a new question in order to focus on these functions more properly. I feel like this is too broad for a single question. About `Strange it seems to last for for 45 though` You didn't actually check the Execution time in the logs, right?

Comment: Using console.time for function calls referenced, I totalled 34 seconds for a (rare) successful, completed run not including constructing cards etc. Agreed I now need to focus on optimizing calls and this needs a new question. Still relevant to this though, is I'm now looking for a way to initiate a function run from a Card button click without being subject to the 30 second limit. I did successfully set a timed trigger on click to achieve this, but the apparent minimum 1 minute delay before the trigger function runs isn't fast enough for my use case. Do you know if this is doable?

Comment: @Diagonali `Do you know if this is doable?` No, I don't think it's doable. Using a trigger is a smart workaround, but as you said there's some delay, so you cannot execute all functions right after calling the Action, if these last more than 30 seconds.